# Changing route before long api call finishes overwrites vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have a long api call in my vuex store and if I change the route before it's finished and dispatch the same action from another page with a quicker api call the first call will eventually overwrite the second call. The action looks like this:

```
async getData({ commit }, payload) {
  try {
    const params = {...};

    const res = await axios.get(`/data`, {
      params,
    });

    if (res.status === 200) {
      commit("setData", res.data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    commit("setError", error.response);
  }
},
```

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to prevent the 'last to finish' async call from overwriting the state, you need to cancel any old actions so they don't complete.

In your example, since you are using `axios`, the easiest option is to use an `AbortController`.

In your action, attach the controller to the `axios` method via the `signal` param:

```
const controller = new AbortController()

let result = axios.get('/foo/bar', { signal: controller.signal })
```

Then when you need to cancel it (i.e before calling a new action, simply call):

```
controller.abort()
```